Experiencing FOUC with Basic Example of Material Web Components
I'm currently implementing a super basic example using Material Web Components as described in their official documentation on GitHub, but I'm encountering an issue with a Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC) when the page loads. The components appear unstyled briefly before the correct styles are applied. I'm looking for insights into why this is happening and how to resolve it.
The issue occurs only one the first load (I guess it should be cache work) so in order to observe it again a clean refresh is needed

Confirm cache: use browser tools (chome) options: disable cache while DevTools is open then refresh your page with devtools open a few times.

"I'm looking for insights into why this is happening" It's likely that content is being rendered before the dependencies have been loaded fully.

Best option (IMO) for third party angular controls - hide the page content (with a "loading...") until angular has loaded.

I am using native JS and that is the only solution I found to hide all the body and display it when DOMContentLoaded and even with this the font changes after

Can you use a CDN?  Then your user might already have it loaded (ie cached from another site)

Only after you decorated the room with your furniture, you bring in the rolls of wallpaper.
That is the FOUC
Your biggest problem is Material Design; how much of it is required to draw you first page?
Before you start other solutions that will always delay furniture delivery  I would first take an hour and see what from Material Design you can copy to a <style> in the <head> of your main document.
